# How do I retrieve the source account, memo, and amount using python?

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-laboratory, python-sdk

How can I retrieve:

- transaction amount
- memo
- source Account

from envelope_xdr  using the python sdk?

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit, I am not the most familiar with the [Python Stellar Base](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/tree/f9e0df25c71cdfe1366cdb8e91b651c28ff5f305), however I have heard great things about it!

Gave it a quick look and saw that it does have methods for parsing XDR. Take the [Asset](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/blob/f9e0df25c71cdfe1366cdb8e91b651c28ff5f305/stellar_base/asset.py#L121) class for example. Here you can see we have a `from_xdr_object` method that takes in XDR and outputs an `Asset`.

I believe this is the type of functionality you are looking for.

Here is some rough Python Code (*just skimmed repo to get something to work and threw this together as POC*:

```
import stellar_base.transaction_envelope as TxEnv
import stellar_base.transaction as Tx

xdr_object = TxEnv.TransactionEnvelope.from_xdr(INSERT_XDR_HERE).to_xdr_object()

tx_object = Tx.Transaction.from_xdr_object(xdr_object)

source_account = tx_object.source
```

**TLDR**: functionality is all there!